# Warning in xcode 4.0.1 about inability to link a static ios framework

Tags: iphone, xcode4

i have upgraded my xcode to 4.0.1 in that i am tring to run my old project which built on xcode 3 but am getting following warning can any one tell me how to fix that

ld: warning: directory not found for option '-F/Developer/new xcode/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS3.1.2.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks'

Comment: How about posting this question under only one of your accounts instead of using two separate accounts to post twice? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5563528/warning-with-xcode-4-0-1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to update your linked frameworks.

Go into your project's build phases, and relink the frameworks...

[image]

**EDIT**

Also check the frameworks search path setting, in your project's build settings.

Comment: sorry i didnot get you.Can you please explain how to do that

Comment: I think this is not a very clear answer. What does "relink the frameworks" mean?